# React : How to pass array of ids to method

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a table which have a button and button have `onClick()` function, I am passing a method to `onclick`, But the ids are in an array.

i can `console.log` like `props.requests[0].objectId`.

```
const actionButton = (published) => {
    if (props.userType === 'crick') {
      if (props.data.verified) {
        return published === true ? <Label>Published</Label> : <Button basic onClick={() => scoreAction(// Have to pass ids here)} >Publish</Button>;
      }
    }
}
```

And the table is below from the above code.

```
   <Table.Body>
      {props.loanRequests.map((value, i) =>
    (<Table.Row key={i}>
      <Table.Cell> {value.cric.name}  </Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell> {value.runs}  </Table.Cell>
      <Table.Cell> {actionButton(value.published)} </Table.Cell>
    </Table.Row>))}
   </Table.Body>
```

How can i pass the array of ids to the button's onclick function method.

**Note** : Semantic UI is in use.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Where are those ids?

Answer (score 2):

Why not pass the entire object in to actionButton?

`<Table.Cell> {actionButton(value)} </Table.Cell>`

Then inside `actionButton` you can reference the properties.

```
const actionButton = (request) => {
    const {id, published} = request;
    if (props.userType === 'crick') {
      if (props.data.verified) {
        return published === true ? <Label>Published</Label> : <Button basic onClick={() => scoreAction(id)} >Publish</Button>;
      }
    }
}
```